# TransactWriteItems Java: How to get response using ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB `TransactWriteItems` API and the doc says we can use `ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure` field to get item attributes when a condition check fails. I made a `TransactWriteItems` call with `ReturnValuesOnConditionCheckFailure` set to `ALL_OLD`:

```
try {
    client.transactWriteItems(placeOrderTransaction);
    System.out.println("Transaction Successful");
    } catch (TransactionCanceledException tce) {
    System.out.println("Transaction Canceled " + tce.getMessage());
}
```

But in console I only see:

> `Transaction Canceled Transaction cancelled, please refer cancellation reasons for specific reasons [ConditionalCheckFailed, None, ConditionalCheckFailed] (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: TransactionCanceledException; Request ID: b25d2b81-38d7-4c83-a17f-52ca4b71ec21)`

Where could I get the item attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You can get item by below code. But the item map is blank and I am not sure how to enable AWS service to send the items as well in the Cancellation reason.

```
TransactionCanceledException e // (from the catch)
List<CancellationReason> reasons = e.cancellationReasons();
        reasons.forEach(reason -> {
            reason.item();
        });
```